# rendering of initial line break after pre tag xhtml

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Compare the rendering of these two links in FireFox:

https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/misc/temp.xhtml

https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/misc/temp.html

The file content is identical.  The file with the xhtml extension renders with an extra line before the content of the pre element.  What part of the specification requires this?  (Aside: Edge renders the two identically; Chrome renders them like FireFox.)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have never followed SGML rules. SGML was just a convenient language in which to define HTML. HTML5 drops any pretence that it is SGML based.

HTML5 specifically requires that its HTML parser drops an initial line feed following a `pre` or `listing` element, but an XML parser is not allowed to do that.

However, I don't know of any spec that requires the browser to subsequently preserve the initial line feed, so Edge's behaviour may not be in error.

Comment: Note that Alohci goes into more detail in the answer to the duplicate.